# 'str' object does not support item assignment in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, readline, readlines

I want to read the input.txt line by line and send that as a request to the server and later save the response respectively. how to read and write the data line by line ?
my code below works for just one input within input.txt (ex : I am Hungry). Can you please help me how to do it for multiple input ?
I did as below. now throwing an error as : File "tts.py", line 198, in 
    TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"] =  line 
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

my code :

```
TEXT_TO_READ = """{

    "tts_type": "text",

    "tts_input": "DUMMY"

}"""
TEXT_TO_READ = json.loads(TEXT_TO_READ)
scriptPath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
scriptPath = os.path.dirname(scriptPath)
fileInput = os.path.join(scriptPath, "input.txt")
try:
    content = open(fileInput, "r")
except IOError:
    print "error message"
    Error_Status = 1
    sys.exit(Error_Status)
for line in content.readlines():
    if len(line):
        TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"]=line.strip('\n')
        TEXT_TO_READ = json.dumps(TEXT_TO_READ)
        print TEXT_TO_READ

request = Request()
```

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question.

Comment: sorry. can you tell me how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You replaced `TEXT_TO_READ` with a JSON string:

```
TEXT_TO_READ = json.dumps(TEXT_TO_READ)
```

The next iteration you no longer have a dictionary, but a string, so your assignment fails:

```
TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"]=line.strip('\n')
```

Don't use the same variable for both encoded JSON data and a dictionary.

Comment: what should i modify here ?

Comment: @sam: what are you trying to achieve? You could just do `print json.dumps(TEXT_TO_READ)` if all you want to do is write the JSON encoding to stdout. That avoids setting `TEXT_TO_READ` altogether.

Comment: after reading first line from the input.txt then sending a request to the server later again  reading the second line and sending the request. but the input here is tts_input. to access tts_input, we are using json loads

Comment: You are only using `json.loads()` to load a hard-coded string at the start of your script. You are not using it on the file contents, if that was the goal.

Comment: No, not really. I can only tell you why you got the error.